# How to find Plan and Marketplace details for a given Azure VM Image reference

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to deploy a `Suse Manager 4.3` Azure VM using Terraform provider. But I keep getting error as mentioned below.
I suspect either the plan or marketplace argeement is wrong.

### Terraform snippet:

```
resource "azurerm_marketplace_agreement" "suse_agree" {
  publisher = "Suseirelandltd1692213356027"
  offer     = "manager-server-4-3-ltd-image"
  plan      = "payg"
}

resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "vm4susemanager" {
  name                = "vm01"
  location            = "westeurope"
  resource_group_name = "my-rg"
  # ..
  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "Suseirelandltd1692213356027"
    offer     = "manager-server-4-3-ltd-image"
    sku       = "gen2"
    #version   = "2023.11.27"
    version   = "latest"
  }

  plan {
    name = "payg"
    publisher = "Suseirelandltd1692213356027"
    product = "manager-server-4-3-ltd-image"
  }
  depends_on = [ azurerm_marketplace_agreement.suse_agree ]
}
```

#### Error:

```
│ Error: creating Linux Virtual Machine (Subscription: "XXX"
│ Resource Group Name: "XXX"
│ Virtual Machine Name: "XXX"): compute.VirtualMachinesClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="ResourcePurchaseValidationFailed" Message="User failed validation to purchase resources. Error message: 'The plan with ID 'payg' was not found. Try one of these: 1- Make sure the plan name is written correctly. 2- If this plan was recently created, allow up to 30 minutes for it to be available. 3- The subscription you're using is associated with Market IN which doesn't support this plan. Try using a different subscription. 4- The subscription/tenant you're using isn't part of the plan's private audience. Ask the offer publisher to add your subscription/tenant to the plan's private audience. subscription ID: XXX. Publisher ID: 'suseirelandltd1692213356027', Offer ID: 'manager-server-4-3-ltd-image', Plan ID: 'payg', Correlation ID: 'XXX'.'"
```

I tried using Az Powershell cmdlets, but unable to figure out this:

```
$pubName="Suseirelandltd1692213356027"
$locName="westeurope"
$offerName = "manager-server-4-3-ltd-image"
$skuName="gen2"

Get-AzVMImageOffer -Location $locName -PublisherName $pubName | Select Offer
Get-AzVMImageSku -Location $locName -PublisherName $pubName -Offer $offerName | Select Skus
Get-AzVMImage -Location $locName -PublisherName $pubName -Offer $offerName -Sku $skuName | Select Version

Get-AzMarketplaceTerms -Publisher "suseirelandltd1692213356027" -Product "manager-server-4-3-ltd-image" -Name "payg"
```

Comment: To use SUSE Manager 4.3 from the Azure Marketplace, you need to update the plan value in both the azurerm_marketplace_agreement and azurerm_linux_virtual_machine resources. Make sure that the plan name matches the one specified in the Azure Marketplace for SUSE Manager 4.3.

Comment: @VinayB Yes, I have specified both as you see in manifest. However, I am unable to find a plan that suits the `Payg` agreement.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to deploy a `Suse Manager 4.3` Azure VM using Terraform provider.But I keep getting error as mentioned below.

```
Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="ResourcePurchaseValidationFailed" Message="User failed validation to purchase resources. Error message: 'The plan with ID 'payg' was not found. Try one of these: 1- Make sure the plan name is written correctly. 2- If this plan was recently created, allow up to 30 minutes for it to be available. 3- The subscription you're using is associated with Market IN which doesn't support this plan. Try using a different subscription. 4- The subscription/tenant you're using isn't part of the plan's private audience. Ask the offer publisher to add your subscription/tenant to the plan's private audience. subscription ID: XXX. Publisher ID: 'suseirelandltd1692213356027', Offer ID: 'manager-server-4-3-ltd-image', Plan ID: 'payg', Correlation ID: 'XXX'.'"
```

The above error you encountered is because you are passing the wrong **publisher** and **offer** details for **Suse Manager 4.3**.

In the code, you are passing version **5.5** with the `publisher` 'Suseirelandltd1692213356027' and offer 'manager-server-4-3-ltd-image' ('manager-server-4-3-byos').

Here are the correct details for **Suse Manager 4.3**.

```
publisher  =  "suse"
offer  =  "manager-server-4-3-byos"
sku  =  "gen2"
version  =  "latest"
```

**SUSU 4.3**

[image]

**SUSU 5.5**

[image]

**Terraform code**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  tenant_id = ""
}
data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name = "venkat"
}
resource "azurerm_marketplace_agreement" "suse_agree" {
  publisher = "suse"
  offer     = "manager-server-4-3-byos"
  plan      = "payg"
}
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "example-network1"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "internal1"
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "example" {
  name                = "example-nic1"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal1"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.example.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "example" {
  name                = "susu-linuxmachine1"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  size                = "Standard_D2s_v3"  
  admin_username      = "adminuser"
  network_interface_ids = [
    azurerm_network_interface.example.id,
  ]

  admin_ssh_key {
    username   = "adminuser"
    public_key = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub")
  }

  os_disk {
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "suse"
    offer     = "manager-server-4-3-byos"
    sku       = "gen2"
    version   = "latest"
  }
  depends_on = [ azurerm_marketplace_agreement.suse_agree ]
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Suse Manager 4.3** `Azure VM` has been successfully created.

[image]

Reference:  [Private Azure Marketplace value and benefits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/create-manage-private-azure-marketplace-new#private-azure-marketplace-value-and-benefits)

Comment: This is not the correct Image. I am still getting error for Image URN: `suseirelandltd1692213356027:manager-server-4-3-ltd-image:gen2:2023.11.27` : `Unable to deploy from the Marketplace image or a custom image sourced from Marketplace image. The part number in the purchase information for VM is not as expected. Beware that the Plan object's properties are case-sensitive.`

Comment: If you are using Suseirelandltd1692213356027, kindly check the offer details for the same image, as it comes in SUSU 5.5. Please check the SUSU 5.5 image details in the portal or as mentioned in the screenshot above.